# URDF joints not appearing in Gazebo

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a URDF model (defined in a .xacro file) of a UUV, and I am trying to enable the robot to be controllable via ROS. I believe my issue lies on the Gazebo side, which is why I'm asking this here.

Here is a snippet of my URDF:

```
  <joint name="base_to_physics" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="base_link_physics"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
    <dynamics damping="0.7"/>
  </joint>

  <joint name="base_to_sonar" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link_physics"/>
    <child link="sonar"/>
    <origin rpy="0 ${-pi/2} ${-pi/2}" xyz="${l4_length/2} ${-((l4_width/2)-sonar_radius-l4_vframe_width)} ${-(-l4_top_height -((l4_height - l4_top_height)/2))}"/>
  </joint>

  <joint name="base_to_camera" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link_physics"/>
    <child link="camera"/>
    <origin rpy="${pi} ${-pi/2} 0" xyz="${l4_length/2} ${(l4_width/2)-sonar_radius-l4_vframe_width} ${l4_top_height+((l4_height - l4_top_height)/2)-camera_lens_center_offset}"/>
  </joint>

  <joint name="base_to_imu" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link_physics"/>
    <child link="imu"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 ${(l4_width/2 - l4_width/6 - imu_width/2)} ${l4_top_height + imu_height/2}"/>
  </joint>

  <joint name="base_to_depth" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link_physics"/>
    <child link="depth_sensor"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 ${(-l4_width/2 + l4_width/6 + imu_width/2)} ${l4_top_height + imu_height/2}"/>
  </joint>
```

However, when I launch gazebo in ROS using this command:

```
  <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-param robot_description -urdf -model vector_l4" />
```

...then I get this error:

```
[ERROR] [1409750686.829834847, 2469.509000000]: This robot has a joint named "base_to_physics" which is not in the gazebo model.
```

What I notice, and this is what makes me think it's a gazebo problem, is that in the Gazebo visualizer, if I select the robot and go to View->Joints, then no joints appear in the "Joints" tab on the right side of the window.

The only other example of this problem that I've seen is on the [ROS answers site](http://answers.ros.org/question/102276/this-robot-has-a-joint-named-foo-which-is-not-in-the-gazebo-model/), but I have already implemented the fix detailed therein and my issue remains.

So how can I get my URDF joints to show up in Gazebo? Am I missing a tag within my joint definitions? I'm using ROS Indigo Igloo and both gzclient and gzserver report version 4.0.1.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6944/urdf-joints-not-appearing-in-gazebo/) by [Tom Moore](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/954/tom-moore/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-09-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

All the the joints shown in your snippet are `fixed`. Gazebo merges all links connected by `fixed` joints into a single link. In your case, no joints will be present.

This is done because a `fixed` joint can only be represented as a revolute joint with zero limits. This dramatically increases the computation required by the physics engine.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/954/tom-moore/) on 2014-09-03**:
Thank you!